# Attempt to create tag on commit failed due to unknown field name

Tags: git, tags

I wish to create new tag on one of my commits which is already pushed to origin using Sourcetree .

```
git --no-optional-locks -c color.branch=false -c color.diff=false -c color.status=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree tag -a -m  RC123 3eaa22c1103ae52413ff8db0f31552ff277171c5
```

However, I keep getting the following error :
`fatal: unknown field name: 5.6`

I've tried to create tag on other commits in my project as well and also tried to create tag from terminal without the extra params but still got the same result.

I don't know where is that `5.6` taken from, but I had other tags which might contain the `5.6` string. What should I do in order to regain the ability to create tags ? Will re-cloning the repository may help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So all my attempts to create tag on my own machine have failed on all clones I've created, but surprisingly I could create the tag when cloning the project to another machine.

this finding hinted that the problem must be related to git machine configuration. and indeed, the file `~/.gitconfig` contained the following section

```
[tag]
        sort = -version:5.6
```

Removing these 2 lines resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is definitely odd.

The command itself is a little odd, but should not produce that error.  Here it is broken up into parts, along with what each one means:

> ```
> git
> ```

Invokes Git, of course.

> ```
> --no-optional-locks
> ```

Prevents Git from using locks when running read-only commands like `git status`.  (Users should almost never use this flag.)  Since the command you're using is not read-only—creating a tag does require creating locks—this flag has no real function here.

> (multiple `-c` options, omitted)

These override any configured `git config` settings for each of the `-c variable=value` settings, using the command-line settings intead.  None of the ones used here are useful, but none are harmful either, as `git tag` itself does not use any of these.

> ```
> tag
> ```

Invokes Git's `tag` sub-command, for tag-reading or tag-setting.

> ```
> -a
> ```

Instructs Git to create an *annotated tag*, which is one with a message in it.

> ```
> -m RC123
> ```

This provides the message.  `RC123` seems like an odd message.  It seems likely that you wanted some other message, and to use `RC123` as the *tag* name, but since `-m` consumes the next word as the message, `RC123` becomes the message.

> ```
> 3eaa22c1103ae52413ff8db0f31552ff277171c5
> ```

This is the name of the new tag.  It strongly resembles a hash ID, and hence will be terrible for use as an actual tag.

Since no *hash ID* is provided, the commit to which the new tag `3eaa22c1103ae52413ff8db0f31552ff277171c5` will attach is the current (`HEAD`) commit.  If you run `git rev-parse HEAD` you'll see what hash ID the new tag `3eaa22c1103ae52413ff8db0f31552ff277171c5` will identify.

> However, I keep getting the following error: `fatal: unknown field name: 5.6`

This is the kind of thing you'd get with a `git for-each-ref` or `git tag` command that's *listing* tags, according to some `--format` directive.  It should not be produced by the `git tag -a -m RC123 tag-name` command you showed.

> What should I do in order to regain the ability to create tags?

From the command line (bash, zsh, DOS/Windows CLI, etc.), you should still be able to create tags.  If you're using some complicated GUI, perhaps it needs to be reconfigured somehow.

> Will re-cloning the repository may help?

There's nothing fundamentally wrong in the *Git* end of things.  Whether re-cloning might help some third-party GUI, well, who knows?  Perhaps tagging the question with the GUI might help (if it's [atlassian-sourcetree](/questions/tagged/atlassian-sourcetree) for instance, use that tag).

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same message even when I run the command manually from terminal without any additional flag. `git tag -m RC123 3eaa22c1103ae52413ff8db0f31552ff277171c5 
fatal: unknown field name: 5.6
`

Comment: Well, that's definitely weird. Does `GIT_TRACE=1 git tag -m RC123 3eaa22c1103ae52413ff8db0f31552ff277171c5` show anything useful? (Mine doesn't really, but mine also doesn't produce this weird error.)